# Responsive CSS for 11in laptop computer size

Tags: css, responsive-design

The media queries are starting to drive me crazy when it comes to responsive design!

We're building a site where the customer has an 11.5" Sony Vaio laptop that is connected to a secondary 20" desktop screen. The css is recognizing the 11" laptop and acting accordingly on both screens.

The site however is not switching to the mobile nav, but instead keeping the desktop nav and overlapping terribly.

The site responds properly on tablets and smartphones, just not on this 11.5" screen.

We're using Bootstrap for the website framework:
http://getbootstrap.com/

Any suggestions on how I can target this super small laptop screen??

Comment: What is the resolution of the screen? 1366x768?

Comment: Yes I believe that is the screen res. At least that's what I find on the Sony website for the specs.

Answer (score 1):

I always forget to add

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,
        maximum-scale=3.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
    ...
</head>
```

That makes your devices reveal their device width and set its scale to default. Usually when I have mobile scaling issues, it's because this guy is missing.

Edit: here is a link to [the Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mobile%2FViewport_meta_tag) regarding this feature.

Comment: Explain what it actually does, rather than just 'play nicely'.

Comment: Good answer! I forgot this a couple of times as well!I do have the following in the header
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`